# Pentaho Kettle - Rest Client Unauthorized for HTTP Method DELETE

Tags: rest, http, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm working on Pentaho 7.1 and i'm using a rest client to perform activities through a specific URL.

Authentication parameters such as Username and Password are properly set, in fact when i'm using HTTP Method "GET" that works fine and i get the Json i'm expecting.

The server i'm contacting (JIRA) exposes as well DELETE HTTP Method, that is what i need.

So, changing HTTP Method results in an unauthorized response, while the same works fine for example in Postman.

I have already tried in postman to see what is my Authentication Header, copying it and using it as a header (injecting a field from a previous step as a constant).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go deep just 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html
enable logging (or just capture traffic).

See the difference between Postman and Pentaho, apply the fix. Done.